# For longitudinal design, should I correlate baseline values with the values at another time point or the change in those values across time?

Tags: longitudinal-data-analysis

I am currently doing an longitudinal analysis and was uncertain about this.

As an example, say you were trying to predict the decline in a person's memory functioning over a period of two years by looking at their baseline value.

Would you want to correlate their baseline values with:

The values reported on Year 2

or

The change in those values from year 1 to year 2?

Answer (score 0):

It ends up being irrelevant. The best approach for description and infernebce is the foundation of the ANCOVA model: fit a linear model where year 2 memory functioning is the *outcome* and the year 1 memory functioning is the *predictor of interest*. This modeling framework allows for the addition of other possible precision adjustments and interactions.